# Реализация интерфейса Comparable

Tags: java

Помогите реализовать интерфейс для класса Per интерфейс Comparable.

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.Comparator; 
import java.util.List;
public class ComparatorDemo {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(                
            new Person("Joe", 24),                
            new Person("Pete", 18),                
            new Person("Chris", 21)        
            );        
        Collections.sort(people, new LexicographicComparator());        
        System.out.println(people);        
        Collections.sort(people, new AgeComparator());        
        System.out.println(people);    
    } 
}
class LexicographicComparator implements Comparator<Person> {    
    @Override    
    public int compare(Person a, Person b) {        
        return a.name.compareToIgnoreCase(b.name);    
    } 
}
class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Person> {    
    @Override    
    public int compare(Person a, Person b) {        
        return a.age < b.age ? -1 : a.age == b.age ? 0 : 1;    
    } 
}
class Per {
    String name;    
    int age;
    Person(String n, int a) {        
        name = n;        
        age = a;    
    }
    @Override    
    public String toString() {        
        return String.format("\nname=%s, age=%d", name, age);    
    } 
}
```

Comment: и в чем ошибка?

Comment: @michael_best для Per не реализован компаратор

Comment: Может, у вас очепятка и `Per` - это все-таки `Person`?

Comment: Всё у вас реализовано. Единственное замечание - `int` лучше сравнивать так: `Integer.compare(a.age, b.age)`

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець это вместо чего?

Comment: @Apper вместо `a.age < b.age ? -1 : a.age == b.age ? 0 : 1`. Мне даже IDEA подсказывает...

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець так что ли?
`public int compare(Person a, Person b) {        
  return Integer.compare(a.age, b.age)   
 }`

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Сейчас с телефона, нету доступа к IDEA

Comment: ну да! Зачем выдумывать велосипед... А еще лучше вместо создания целого класса компаратора написать так: `people.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));` (Нужно создать геттер для возраста)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вопросе вы спрашиваете про интерфейс, в коде же реализовано несколько компараторов. Если проблема в этом, то нужно дополнить описание класса ключевым словом `implements` с названием интерфейса и переопределить метод `compareTo` нужным для вас образом:

```
class Person implements Comparable {
    String name;
    int age;
    Person(String n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("\nname=%s, age=%d", name, age);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return 0; // вместо 0 верните то что считаете нужным  
    }
}
```